# Get list of Files in Google Cloud Storage (Appengine PHP)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket "MyBucket" and it have 20 items. I would like to get those file name in my appengine PHP application.

I'm Looking whether we can get the list using App Engine's built-in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) stream wrapper.

Something Like this:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$bucket_name = 'gs://my-bucket/';
$file_list = CloudStorageTools::list($bucket_name); //Won't Work. Function like this
```

Answer (score 1):

based on 
[ref. documentation for CloudStorateTools](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/files/google.appengine.api.cloud_storage.CloudStorageTools#%5Cgoogle%5Cappengine%5Capi%5Ccloud_storage%5CCloudStorageTools) there is no such thing like listing files. Consider to use different API for accessing Google Cloud Storage like JSON API. For list function you can check this [link](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list).

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer. I hope this is correct . It is strange we cannot find this on documentation for php.

```
        $storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
        $listObjects = $storage->objects->listObjects($bucket, array());
        $items = $listObjects->getItems();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
           print_r($item["name"]);
        }
```