# How to list files stored in google cloud storage bucket in wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to list files that are available in my Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Are there any plugins for that?

I want to pass the folder name as an argument , (sort of like shortcode), then the shortcode can fetch the files from the folder and list them, if possible with metadata. I believe a plugin will be available, or a bunch of plugins for a workaround.

If there aren't any plugins for that, please point me in the right direction as to what PHP functions I should learn about to do it myself.

```
if ( function_exists( 'switch_to_blog' ) ) switch_to_blog(1);
$murl = get_option( 'siteurl' ) . $mdir;
if ( function_exists( 'restore_current_blog' ) ) restore_current_blog();
// MP3 folder relative URL
$mrelative = preg_replace( '/^https?\:/m', '', $murl );
$mrelative = preg_replace( '/^\/\//', '', $mrelative );
$mrelative = explode( '/', $mrelative );
array_shift($mrelative);
$mrelative = '/'.implode('/', $mrelative);

$mpath = ABSPATH . mb_substr($mdir, 1);
```

The above code reads folders from the local server, instead I want the URL to be custom, where do I input the custom URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with Google APIs and get the list of objects in a GCS bucket.

Similar answer can be found here: [Get list of Files in Google Cloud Storage (Appengine PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657549/get-list-of-files-in-google-cloud-storage-appengine-php)

Comment: but that code doesn't take a foldername for argument and scan the files in it.

Comment: There are no folders in object store.

Comment: You can provide the full gs:// path which you want to list and should work

Comment: it will be great if you could show an example code.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage doesn’t have a folder structure.  [How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) is a good read for some background.

There is actually a plugin for this listed in the [Wordpress site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gcs/#installation) provided by Google and also another one widely spread in the community called [WP-Stateless](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/)

You can also implement a custom solution if you want using the official [Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php) but I believe that the plugins are enough for you at the moment.

You can list objects from a GCS bucket using this example code:

```
$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($this->gcsClient);
$listObjects = $storage->objects->listObjects($this->bucket, array());
$items = $listObjects->getItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    print_r($item["name"]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does your code do? adding coments to your code would be helpfull

Comment: The above code looks for mp3 files in the folders specified in the shortcode. I want the same to happen for GCS objects.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example on how to list files in a bucket in PHP, does this help you?

Comment: WP-Stateless doesn't allow us to use a shortcode to specify a foldername to list media files., This code you have updated with means a lot. Thank you so much, but how to specify foldername/directoryname in the bucket, Can I also get metadata of the files, and the url of the files by replacing the "name"?

Comment: Hi Chris32, I read about the gcs objects and their structure after you metntioned, Now if suppose, I need to read files from a subdirectory, eg:. gs://example.com/music/abcdef/, how do I fetch files from there?. Is it allowed for the directories to be given dynamically.?. Like $foldername=array[i], and then gs://example.com/music/$foldername??

Comment: If you need to access an array of folders you can simply create a function as I shared in my answer. This function receive a string which in your case is the name of the file and just pass this variable. Then you can use the function inside of a loop and iterate trough each element in the array.
Also you can get the metadata of an object as:
`$storage = new StorageClient();`
`$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);`
`$object = $bucket->object($objectName);`
`$info = $object->info();`

Comment: You can find usefull [this Github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/src) with a lot of examples on how to perform actions on Google Cloud Storage with PHP